# Issue in synchronous working of localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage, react-hooks

I am trying to get useremail from localstorage, but the email is not being updated instantly.
Solutions i have tried -
 
1. Using email in dependency array, this updates the email but people is not re-rendered in DOM
2. Using both email and people in dependency array, which is causing infinite calling of useEffect.
3.I have tried it without promise, directly in sequential flow which is also not updating email.
Please suggest the correct way of handling this.

```
    const [people,setPeople]=useState([])
    const [email,setEmail] = useState('')
    useEffect(()=>{
        new Promise((res,rej)=>{
            setEmail(localStorage.getItem('userid')) //here is issue
            if(email) res();
            else rej(email);
        }).then(
            fire.firestore()
            .collection('Users').where('Email','==',email)
            .get().then((snapshot)=>{
                console.log(snapshot)
                setPeople(snapshot.docs[0].data().Name)
            })
            .catch(e=>{console.log(e)})
        )
        .catch((e)=>{console.log(e)})

    },[email,people])
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wrapping the localStorage call in Promise makes it complicated. You need to make the firestore call when the email changes. Below are two solutions I can suggest.

1. The first one only runs when the component mounts and eliminates the email from state.

```js
const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  // you might need to wrap this in a try catch as it may fail if a user has disabled access to localStorag
  const email = localStorage.getItem("userid");

  if (email) {
    fire
      .firestore()
      .collection("Users")
      .where("Email", "==", email)
      .get()
      .then((snapshot) => {
        console.log(snapshot);
        setPeople(snapshot.docs[0].data().Name);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  }
}, []);
```

2. If you want the fire store effect to run whenever the email changes.
   You can seperate the two effects and make the firestore effect depend on email changes as shown below.

```js
const [people, setPeople] = useState([]);
const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

useEffect(() => {
  const localStorageEmail = localStorage.getItem("userid");
  if (email) {
    setEmail(localStorageEmail);
  }
}); // dependence array ignored will run everytime the component rerenders

useEffect(() => {
  if (!email) return;

  fire
    .firestore()
    .collection("Users")
    .where("Email", "==", email)
    .get()
    .then((snapshot) => {
      console.log(snapshot);
      setPeople(snapshot.docs[0].data().Name);
    })
    .catch((e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
}, [email]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can separate function getting email and people. I assume you want to get people only when having an email.

- Getting email after component initially rendered
- Then create `useEffect` for `fire.firestore()...` dependencies is email

```js
   const [people,setPeople]=useState([])
    const [email,setEmail] = useState('')
    useEffect(()=>{
        setEmail(localStorage.getItem('userid'))
    },[])
    
    useEffect(()=>{
     if(email){
        fire.firestore()
            .collection('Users').where('Email','==',email)
            .get().then((snapshot)=>{
                console.log(snapshot)
                setPeople(snapshot.docs[0].data().Name)
            })
            .catch(e=>{console.log(e)})
      } 
    },[email])
```